# Print raw control characters while preserving string delimiters in output (Racket)

Tags: formatting, scheme, racket, double-quotes, quotation-marks

I have a list in Racket like so:

```
'(some-symbol
  "some\ntext\ngoes in\nhere")
```

I want to print it out such that control characters like `\n` are translated to their actual values, in this case a linefeed. However, I also want the quotation marks of the string (i.e., the delimiters) to be preserved in the output a la `write` or `print`. The `display` function already does the first part of what I want, but it strips out quotation marks that are not escaped like `\"`. E.g.:

```
racket@> (displayln '(some-symbol "some\ntext\ngoes in\nhere")) ;; I want the linefeeds as produced here
(some-symbol some
text
goes in
here)
racket@> (println '(some-symbol "some\ntext\ngoes in\nhere")) ;; But I also want the quotation marks as preserved here
'(some-symbol "some\ntext\ngoes in\nhere")
racket@>
```

Is there some way to get this sort of output effect in Racket without escaping string delimiters like `\"`? Also, I do not want the `'` character, which precedes the list, in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want, so let's put a straw man out there for you to bash around:

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

;; find every string in an s-expression, add quotes to it:
(define (add-quotes s)
  (cond [(list? s)
         (map add-quotes s)]
        [(string? s)
         (string-append "\"" s "\"")]
        [else s]))

(check-equal? (add-quotes '((a b "cde") (("g") f)))
              '((a b "\"cde\"") (("\"g\"") f)))

;; display s with quotes around strings:
(define (funny-display s)
  (display (add-quotes s)))
```

Not what you wanted?

Comment: This does what I want; thank you. Sorry if my question wasn't very clear.